# set fetchSize in JDBC in Spark 2.x?

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, jdbc

fetchSize error:

> TypeError: jdbc() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fetchSize'

I tried reading as

```
mydf = spark.read.jdbc(url, table, numPartitions=20, column=partitionColumn, lowerBound=0, upperBound=1000, fetchSize = 10000, properties=properties)
```

Comment: Is it coincidence that [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53625373/how-to-set-jdbc-fetchsize-in-spark-2-3-1) was asked two hours before you did?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure of performance but try this below code. this will not throw error

```
df = (spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", url)
  .option("dbtable", "mytable") 
  .option("user", user) .option("password", password) 
  .option("numPartitions", "100").option("fetchsize","10000")
  .option("partitionColumn", "id")
  .option("lowerBound", "1").option("upperBound","1000000").load())
```